# Installation of windows 10 on Oracle virtual box

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, installation, iso-image

I recently brought a new laptop with installed Windows 10.
I am planning to install Ubuntu as main OS. But I want windows 10 as sub OS. So is it possible to install windows 10 on virtual box for free?

Comment: This article might help you: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-legally-use-windows-10-in-virtualbox/71996

Comment: The current version of VirtualBox is compatible with Windows 10.